# Count distinct characters in SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table of Chinese words. A Chinese word is made up of multiple characters, similar to how English words are made of multiple letters. Unlike the English alphabet though, there are thousands of different characters.

I want a query to count the number of distinct characters in the table. For example, if the table contained 3 rows

- 你好
- 你们
- 大家好

I'd want the query to return 5, for the distinct characters 你，好，们，大，家.

I'm currently scanning the table and then doing the computation in code, but is it possible to write a SQL query to do this?

Comment: there is a limit for the numbers of characters ina word??

Comment: In practice most are 2-3 characters. 4-5 isn't uncommon though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, 1) c, SUBSTR(col, 2) col
  FROM tablename
  WHERE LENGTH(col) > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, 1), SUBSTR(col, 2)
  FROM cte
  WHERE LENGTH(col) > 0
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c) counter
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9ed791fd1ec3c3cb49dfd5d0c42f2983).
Results:

```
> | counter |
> | ------: |
> |       5 |
```